# Java Stream from List<Object[]> to a List<MyDTO>

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a `List<Object[]>` where the `Object[]` has the size of `3` and comes from a query. The result of the query is as follows:

```
| vehicleId                          | modelId | serviceId       |
|------------------------------------|---------|-----------------|
|93bf3e92-7a37-4e23-836d-eed5a104341f|      214|80a7-ce5640b18879|    
|b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-1d1187de559c|      214|80a7-ce5640b18879|
|ae6cb0fe-1501-4311-a2b4-cfb8b4f51ca4|      214|80a7-ce5640b18879|
|cf80ff11-6e23-4c19-8b6d-55d34d131566|      214|80a7-ce5640b18879|
```

It should be mapped in the List below. The second and last columns will be mapped to modelId and serviceId whilst the first column should become a list of vehicleIds.

I need to map it into a `List<MyDTO>` where `MyDTO` is as follows:

```
MyDTO{

// constructor    
MyDTO(String modelId, String serviceId, List<String> vehicleIds){...}

String modelId;
String serviceId;
List<String> vehicleIds;
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to group by in a stream but nothing seems to come out. That's where I'm blocked...

```
listOfObjectArrays.stream()
            .map(objects -> new MyDTO((String) objects[0], (String) objects[1], null));
```

Can't figure out how to apply a reduce operation that does the job, any help really appreciated!

**Edit:**
Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm stuck with Java 8. Thank you all for the great answers.

Comment: Would you say that modelId and serviceId are the "key" for the list, i.e. each list element has a unique modelId and serviceId combination and possibly multiple vehicleId's?

Comment: Yes I think it's safe to say so

Comment: From which query comes the result? Any chance you are using hibernate?

Comment: It's Hibernate but a native query and jpa 1.x. No way to do an elegant solution creating the Dto on the fly.

Comment: Does the listOfObjectArrays always has only one distinct modelId and only one distinct serviceId?

Comment: What DB are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Java 8

You could map them all to Strings first and then group by the tuple (modelId, serviceId) and only then map the results of the grouping to the dtos.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<MyDto> myDtos = queryResult.stream()
        // cast all to String and put into tuple
        .map(objects -> Arrays.asList((String) objects[0], (String) objects[1], (String) objects[2]))
         // group by tuple (modelid, serviceId)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> Arrays.asList(r.get(1), r.get(2)),
                Collectors.mapping(r -> r.get(0), Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new MyDto(entry.getKey().get(0), entry.getKey().get(1), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Bonus points for Java 14+

To increase readability instead of using lists we introduce records

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

record MyDto(String vehicleId, String modelId, List<String> serviceIds) {
    public MyDto(Map.Entry<AggregateKey, List<String>> vehiclesAggregate) {
        this(vehiclesAggregate.getKey().modelId(), vehiclesAggregate.getKey().serviceId(),vehiclesAggregate.getValue());
    }
}

record ResultRow(String vehicleId, String modelId, String serviceId) {
    public ResultRow(Object[] entries) {
        this((String) entries[0], (String) entries[1], (String) entries[2]);
    }

    public AggregateKey getKey() {
        return new AggregateKey(modelId, serviceId);
    }
}

record AggregateKey(String modelId, String serviceId) {}
```

Resulting in a much shorter and very readable streaming pipeline

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<MyDto> myDtos = queryResult.stream()
    .map(ResultRow::new)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ResultRow::getKey,
            Collectors.mapping(ResultRow::vehicleId, Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(MyDto::new)
    .toList(); // shorthand for collect(Collectors.toList) since Java 16
```

Comment: This would have been the accepted answer. Unfortunately I'm stuck with Java 8 and sorry  I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Java 8 is EOL. You should invest in updating at least to Java 11.

Comment: Well if it was me to decide we would have upgraded jpa version years ago and now I wouldn't need to find hacks for such a simple thing...

Comment: Retaining on an old version is a technical depth. You and your colleagues are paying interest in form of hacking your way to the goal, and maintaining a potential security issue.

Comment: I like the use of a List<> for the representation of a Tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nested intermediate map by grouping your data by `modelId` and then `serviceId` using `groupingBy()` and `mapping()` collectors.

And then create a stream over entry set. And flatten each inner map creating `new MyDTO` based on every combination of `modelId` and `serviceId`.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> vehicleIdByModelIdAndServiceId =
    listOfObjectArrays.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(objects -> (String) objects[1],
            Collectors.groupingBy(objects -> (String) objects[2],
                Collectors.mapping(objects -> (String) objects[0],
                    Collectors.toList()))));
        
List<MyDTO> result = vehicleIdByModelIdAndServiceId.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(baseEntry -> baseEntry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> new MyDTO(baseEntry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another option is to use a `Map.Entry` as a key in the intermediate map, and a value will be a list of `vehicleId`.

```
List<MyDTO> result = listOfObjectArrays.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(objects -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((String) objects[1], (String) objects[2]),
                Collectors.mapping(objects -> (String) objects[0],
                    Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new MyDTO(entry.getKey().getKey(),
                                entry.getKey().getValue(),
                                entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't  need a simple list of DTOs, each DTO must have a list of vehicles created while traversing the stream (sort of group by on serviceid and modelid)

Comment: @Antonio So you need to group results retrieved from the DB by the combination of `modelId` and `serviceId`?

Comment: I have an Cannot resolve method 'entry' in 'Map' here

Comment: @Antonio You are probably using Java 8 (static method `entry()` is accessible with Java 9). It can be substituted with explicit invocation of the constructor `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((String)objects[1],(String)objects[2])`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need to use `stream`, you can always use a standard cycle, for example:

```
Map<String, MyDTO> myDTOs = new HashMap<>();
for(Object[] a : listOfObjectArrays) {
    String key = a[1] + " - " + a[2];
    MyDTO myDTO = myDTOs.get(key);
    if(myDTO == null) {
        List<String> vehicleIds = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicleIds.add((String) a[0]);
        myDTO = new MyDTO((String) a[1], (String) a[2], vehicleIds);
        myDTOs.put(key, myDTO);
    } else {
        myDTO.getVehicleIds().add((String) a[0]);
    }
}

List<MyDTO> myDTOList = new ArrayList<>(myDTOs.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to

- Stream `Object[]` as `{String,Long,String}`
- Group By `{Object[1],Object[2]}`; Collect(Distinct `Object[0]`)
- `Map<List<Object[0]>,{Object[1],Object[2]}>` --> `List<MyDto>`

For this, I setup two supporting classes, one of which you provided, the other one needed as a Key for the `groupingBuy` to work:

```
  class MyDTO{
    String modelId;
    String serviceId;
    List<String> vehicleIds;

    MyDTO(String modelId, String serviceId, String vehicleId) {
      // Need to put in a Modifiable ArrayList so the reduce can happen
      this(modelId,serviceId,new ArrayList<>(List.of(vehicleId)));
    }
    
    MyDTO(String modelId, String serviceId, List<String> vehicleIds){
      this.modelId = modelId;
      this.serviceId = serviceId;
      this.vehicleIds = vehicleIds;
    }
    
    public MyDTOKey getKey() {
      return new MyDTOKey(modelId, serviceId);
    }
    
    public MyDTO reduce(MyDTO other) {
      this.vehicleIds.addAll(other.vehicleIds);
      return this;
    }
    
    public void dump() {
      System.out.println("modelId: "+modelId+"; serviceId: "+serviceId+"; vehicleIds: "+vehicleIds.toString());
    }
  }
```

```
  private class MyDTOKey<T1,T2> {
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2;
    
    public MyDTOKey(T1 v1,T2 v2) {
      this.v1 = v1;
      this.v2 = v2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(v1,v2);
    }

    /*
     * Required for the groupby to work correctly as it
     * doesnt automatically on an Object[]
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) {
        return true;
      }
      if (obj == null) {
        return false;
      }
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
      }
      final MyDTOKey <?, ?> other = (MyDTOKey <?, ?>) obj;
      if (!Objects.equals(this.v1, other.v1)) {
        return false;
      }
      return Objects.equals(this.v2, other.v2);
    }
    
  }
```

And with a heads-on approach, I can build something like this:

```
  List<Object []> data = List.of(
    new Object[]{"93bf3e92-7a37-4e23-836d-eed5a104341f", "214", "80a7-ce5640b18879"},
    new Object[]{"b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-1d1187de559c", "214", "80a7-ce5640b18879"},
    new Object[]{"b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-dddddddddddd", "215", "80a7-ce5640b18879"}
    );

  public static void main(String [] pars) {
    Map<Pair<String,String>,List<String>> map = data
      .stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(
         o->new MyDTOKey((String)o[1],(String)o[2]), // group by last two only
         mapping(
           o->(String)o[0],  // Collapse the vehicle id's to a list 
           toList()          // Using set to take out duplicate vehicle id's
         )
       ));

    // Convert the map to a List.
    List<MyDTO> dtos = map.entrySet().stream()
      .map(e->new MyDTO(e.getKey().v1,e.getKey().v2,e.getValue()))
      .collect(toList());
    
    for (MyDTO dto:dtos) {
      dto.dump();
    }
  }
```

The whole effort of creating a class to represent a Tuple (`MyDTOKey`) can be avoided by setting it up as a `List<String>` as done in @Valerij Doblers answer.

But with some minor tweaking already done to the `MyDTO` class, we can rewrite this also neatly as follows:

```
  public static void main(String [] pars) {
    List<MyDTO> data = List.of(
      new MyDTO("214", "80a7-ce5640b18879","93bf3e92-7a37-4e23-836d-eed5a104341f"),
      new MyDTO("214", "80a7-ce5640b18879","b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-1d1187de559c"),
      new MyDTO("215", "80a7-ce5640b18879","b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-dddddddddddd")
      );
  
    List<MyDTO> dtos = data.stream()
            .collect(
              groupingBy(
                MyDTO::getKey,
                reducing(MyDTO::reduce)
              )
            ) // Produces a Map<MyDTOKey,MyDTO>
            .values().stream() // Streams Optional<MyDTO>
            .flatMap(o->o.stream()) // expand to contained MyDTO
            .collect(toList())
            ;
    

    for (MyDTO dto:dtos) {
      dto.dump();
    }
  }
```

Maybe with a little more effort we can collect directly in a List without going through the Map first.

Answer (score 0):

This needs a Collectors.groupBy() function since you're taking a stream and grouping them together.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class F {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var in = List.of(new Object[]{"93bf3e92-7a37-4e23-836d-eed5a104341f", "214", "80a7-ce5640b18879"},
                new Object[]{"b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-1d1187de559c", "214", "80a7-ce5640b18879"},
                new Object[]{"b4066520-e127-44b7-bcc0-dddddddddddd", "215", "80a7-ce5640b18879"}
        );


        Map<Key, List<MyDTOOne>> p1 =
                in.stream()
                        .map(objs -> new String[]{(String) objs[0], (String) objs[1], (String) objs[2]})
                        .map(objs -> new MyDTOOne(objs[1], objs[2], objs[0]))
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myDTO -> new Key(myDTO.modelId, myDTO.serviceId)));
        List<MyDTO> p2 = p1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new MyDTO(e.getKey().modelId, e.getKey().serviceId, e.getValue().stream().map(MyDTOOne::vehicleId).toList()))
                .toList();

        System.out.println(p2);
    }

    static record Key(String modelId, String serviceId) {

    }

    static record MyDTO(String modelId, String serviceId, List<String> vehicleIds) {

    }

    static record MyDTOOne(String modelId, String serviceId, String vehicleId) {

    }

}
```

https://replit.com/@ArchimedesTraja/Grouping